# Alternatives to PostgreSQL for embedded SQL db in C/C++ applications

Tags: c++, sql, c, database

After searching seems like the only SQL database that is free and can be embedded in a C/C++ application is [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

There are other solutions with a permissive license ? How hard is writing this from the scratch in C/C++ so i can code my own stuff ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "embedded"? PostgreSQL sure can't be run "embedded" (i.e. in-process of your C/C++ application). And what's wrong with PostgreSQL anyway? It's probably the best choice in open-source database right now - and still a very good choice for a database even compared to commercial offerings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the db doesn't exist on the filesystem as separated file/files, the user shouldn't be able to tell that there is an SQL database in this application.

Comment: There is no way you can hide that fact from the user if the application is running on the same computer as the database. There will be database files around and there will be a server process dealing with your query queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the standard answer to this question is [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: sqlite is really bad in terms of performance, i need a support for several K records

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you targeting? For cross-platform use I can't suggest anything but sqlite. If you're targeting windows only, then there is also Microsoft SQL server compact edition to consider.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free database **BerkeleyDB** from **Oracle**. It is available as a C Source code. I used the database with VxWorks. with which OS you want to work with? Do mention these to get correct solutions.

Comment: He said a SQL database, which is not the case of BerkeleyDB.

Comment: @bortzmeyer Oracle added support for SQL in 11g R2 release based on the popular SQLite API by including a version of SQLite in Berkeley DB and i dont know why my answer is down voted.